# matplotlib gtk issue

Tags: matplotlib, gtk, x11

Firstly, I know very very little about Python, Xwindows, Matplotlib or GTK. I am trying to run a tool called SpliceGrapher which uses the above. I get an (ugly, sorry) error:

```
 /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
 warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
 /home/my/bin/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk.py:52: GtkWarning: gdk_cursor_new_for_display: assertion `GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed
 cursors.MOVE          : gdk.Cursor(gdk.FLEUR),
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/my/bin/SpliceGrapher-0.2.0/scripts/view_splicegraphs.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pylab      import *
  File "/home/my/bin/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "/home/my/bin/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pylab.py", line 264, in <module>
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
  File "/home/my/bin/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 95, in <module>
new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/home/my/bin/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 25, in pylab_setup
globals(),locals(),[backend_name])
  File "/home/my/bin/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtkagg.py", line 10, in <module>
from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtk import gtk, FigureManagerGTK, FigureCanvasGTK,\
  File "/home/my/bin/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk.py", line 52, in <module>
    cursors.MOVE          : gdk.Cursor(gdk.FLEUR),
  RuntimeError: could not create GdkCursor object
```

If anyone has any idea what I can do, that would be great.

I am on a Linux (RedHat) system, through puTTy using Xming. I have X11 configured and xeyes shows the little eyes that follow my mouse so I know thats working.

New error:

```
16:00:46 view_splicegraphs.py Started
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/bmoran/bin/SpliceGrapher-0.2.0/scripts/view_splicegraphs.py", line 164, in <module>
g = getFirstGraph(f)
File "/home/bmoran/bin/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/SpliceGrapher/SpliceGraph.py", line 371, in getFirstGraph
result = SpliceGraphParser(f, **args).next()
File "/home/bmoran/bin/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/SpliceGrapher/SpliceGraph.py", line 1351, in __init__
self.loadFromFile()
File "/home/bmoran/bin/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/SpliceGrapher/SpliceGraph.py", line 1424, in loadFromFile
raise ValueError("Graph feature found before graph header at line %d" % lineNo)
ValueError: Graph feature found before graph header at line 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
```

Tells you your script does not have an access to your X session.

Can you post here your script?

Did you access the machine with `ssh -XC ...` ?

on the shell when you issue `echo $DISPLAY` what do you see?
When you add in your script `print os.getenv("DISPLAY")` do you see the same result?

one more note ... I don't know `Xming` but I can recommend you to try [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/), it has a builtin ssh and X11 server compiled for Windows, and my guess is that it will solve your X problem.

Comment: Ok, I have access to X session now, I was logged in through PuTTy but tried MobaXterm.  `echo $DISPLAY` gives If `'localhost:12.0' is not a typo you can run the following command to lookup the package that contains the binary: -bash: localhost:12.0: command not found` My new error message is above, comments are a bit messy!

Comment: @Did you use now mobaxterm? You now have an error in your code. Please put your code here, other wise you are not helping us to help you.

Comment: Got it working on MobaXterm, thanks for the suggestion Oz123=D

Comment: @So, like I thought, the problem is with your X server. Upvote :-D ?